# streambuf::xsgetn and state flags

Tags: c++, iostream

The protected virtual member function `streambuf::xsgetn` enables I/O stream implementors to define a function which extracts `n` characters from an input stream and store them in a buffer.

Normally, for most standard streams like `fstream`, this function simply call `sbumpc` in a loop until `eof` is returned.  But a custom stream class can override this function to do something more efficient, such as copy data in bulk into the output buffer.

But what I don't understand, is how `xsgetn` get indicate that an EOF condition has been reached.  Suppose the user requests a read of 100 bytes, but only 50 bytes are left in the stream.  Presumably, `xsgetn` should read 50 bytes, return `50` and then set the internal stream state to `eof`.

Except `xsget` is a member function of `streambuf`, and it has no way to set the stream state.  And unlike `sbumpc`, which can return `EOF`, xsgetn has no way to indicate that an EOF condition occurred.  So how is `xsgetn` supposed to handle EOF conditions?

Comment: If it read any number of bytes then the end of file condition hasn't yet occurred. The following read that returns 0 is an indication of failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I found on libstdc++:

```
template<typename _CharT, typename _Traits>
streamsize basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::xsgetn(char_type* __s, streamsize __n) {
    streamsize __ret = 0;
    while (__ret < __n) {
        const streamsize __buf_len = this->egptr() - this->gptr();
        if (__buf_len) {
            const streamsize __remaining = __n - __ret;
            const streamsize __len = std::min(__buf_len, __remaining);
            traits_type::copy(__s, this->gptr(), __len);
            __ret += __len;
            __s += __len;
            this->__safe_gbump(__len);
        }

        if (__ret < __n) {
            const int_type __c = this->uflow();
            if (!traits_type::eq_int_type(__c, traits_type::eof())) {
                traits_type::assign(*__s++, traits_type::to_char_type(__c));
                ++__ret;
            } else
                break;
        }
    }
    return __ret;
}
```

When the characters extracted are less than the number of characters requested, this function calls `uflow()` to obtain more characters. If that function returns `Traits::eof()` then it will simply return whether or not 0 characters were extracted. The result of the function call is picked up by the higher-level stream operations that have access to the stream state, and will set it accordingly.